# Why isn't ignoreDupResponse set to true by default in A4J

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

It seems to me that the most of the time you'd want to have ignoreDupResponse set to true on your a4j:support, a4j:commandLink, a4j:commandButton, etc. components. In which scenario it can be useful to have ignoreDupResponse set to false? Is there any performance cost of having ignoreDupResponse set to true? If not, why isn't ignoreDupResponse  set to true by default by A4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a useful example where it should be set tot false.
However, the reason why it is set to false by default is that this is the default/normal behavior. So when it is false, nothing has to happen, while when it is true, the duplicate responses need to be 'filtered'.

By the way: it is client side behavior, so it will not have any effect on your network or server load.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ignoreDupResponse=true will drop the DOM update after a request completes when a similar request (same component or from the same group) is queued. That's not always the desired behavior. Hope this helps.